# How do I access a private maven repo from inside a docker container?

Tags: maven, docker, clojure, leiningen, gnupg

We have a number of web services, written in clojure, and we also have some internal shared dependencies that we keep in a private maven repo. Leiningen requires an encrypted credentials file and at the moment each of our developers has their own private keys that lein uses to decrypt the credentials at runtime. I'm attempting to migrate to containers to make deployment and onboarding easier, but right away I've run into the problem that `lein run` from inside the container can't access my gpg keys, which are of course outside the container. I managed to generate a key inside the container using `docker run bash` and encrypt the credentials using that, but that won't scale as I'd have to keep unencrypted credentials inside the project directory. I'm not sure what the best path forward is - how can I securely pull from the private repo?

Comment: Mount the local keys into the container. `docker run -v ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg:/home/appuser/.gnupg/secring.gpg:ro myservice`

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas which keep credentials secret and do expose them to the target container:

- [Habitus](https://github.com/cloud66/habitus) to manage secret configuration for your build.
- [docker-volume-libsecret](https://github.com/ehazlett/docker-volume-libsecret) to mount secret data into a container.